# Can I use a derived class in a cython extention (cdef class) attribute at runtime?

Tags: python, cython

I have a lazy dictionary (something like a factory) to build singletons in my python library, I store only the type and make an instance only if the object is needed (making the object is time consuming):

(mypythonlib.py)

```
class LazyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        import inspect
        objOrType = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        if inspect.isclass(objOrType):
            objOrType = objOrType()
            dict.__setitem__(self,key,objOrType)
        return objOrType

integrationRuleFromPython = LazyDict()
integrationRuleFromPython["string1"] = myheavyclass1
integrationRuleFromPython["string2"] = myheavyclass2
...
```

then I want to use this dictionary in a cython extension. 
My cython extension looks line this: (integration.pyx)

```
from  mypythonlib import integrationRuleFromPython

cdef class IntegralCpp():
    cdef dict integrationRule

    def __init__(self):
        self.integrationRule = integrationRuleFromPython 
        ...
```

my extension is compiled correctly but at runtime a get:

File "integration.pyx", line 76, in integration.IntegralCpp.**init** TypeError: Expected dict, got LazyDict

Can I use a python derived class to set an attribute in a cython extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you declare a type with `cdef`, it must be an exact type. From the [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#types):

> Also, the Python types `list`, `dict`, `tuple`, etc. may be used for static typing, as well as any user defined [Extension Types](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#extension-types). For example:
>
> ```py
> cdef list foo = []
> ```
>
> This requires an exact match of the class, it does not allow subclasses. This allows Cython to optimize code by accessing internals of the builtin class, which is the main reason for declaring builtin types in the first place.

Aside: In [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance) type annotations this is called "invariance".